# Excel - How do I display the "excel options" dialog using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, file, optionmenu

I want to use vba to display the Save tab from the 'Excel Options' dialog box for our users.
[File > Excel Options > Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFY1p.png)

I'm familiar with the ExecuteMso method. For example, Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity") opens the Macro Security dialog.

I have the complete "Office 2016 Fluent Control list" but after much time looking at excelcontrols file, I can't find the control name to use.

Comment: `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ApplicationOptionsDialog")`

Comment: Thank you Siddharth. "ApplicationOptionsDialog" is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No Problem. I do not remember the control id for `Save`. For example the office id for `Advanced` tab is `522`. So if you run this `Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=522).Execute`, you will get Excel Option with just `Advanced tab` selected.

Comment: That was also a help for another objective. Thank you again Siddharth.